# Facing Problem while connecting the Phantom wallet

Tags: solana-program, nft, phantom-wallet

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to connect the Phantom wallet from my marketplace. The problem is that when someone clicks on "Connect Wallet," the Phantom wallet popup doesn't open. There aren't any related errors displayed in my console or network API. Interestingly, after locking the wallet, performing a hard refresh on the page, logging into the wallet, toggling the developer test mode on and off, and then trying to connect the wallet again, the popup opens, allowing the wallet to be added to my website.

I'm uncertain about the root cause of this issue as there are no errors reported, and only 4 out of 10 people seem to encounter this problem while the other 6 can connect their wallets without any issue. I'm using the Solana wallet adapter package to establish the connection between the wallet and my website. I've reached out to Phantom for assistance via email, but I haven't received a reply yet.

Could this issue possibly stem from the caching mechanisms of Phantom or the web browser? Has anyone else experienced this issue before?

Comment: which cookies are you clearing tho?

Comment: 2 questions: 1) are you working on localhost in dev mode of your app while having these issues? 2) does a hard refresh of your app always fix the problem and the wallet can connect?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue seems to have just been a bug with the wallet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was on QuickNode's side and has now been resolved. –

Answer (score 2):

We faced this issue while using Phantom wallet and this was one of the major reasons we switched to Solflare. It so happens that this stores the wallet in the cookies and it is already connected as per the wallet but the local state is changed so it doesn't show connected. Still waiting for Phantom to give a workaround or some explanation on how to fix this. In the meanwhile clearing browser cookies seems to be the only solution.