# phantom not connecting on a new tab

Tags: phantom

I have a use that does this :

open a new tab, try to connect phantom wallet, nothing happens, no error.
refresh the page, everything works just fine.

We can reproduce this as many times as we try.

I tried the connection with solana wallet adapter and with window.phantom.solana.connect() same results.

I have seen this [Facing Problem while connecting the Phantom wallet](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8271/facing-problem-while-connecting-the-phantom-wallet/9246#9246) and it seems related, but don't really know which cookie to clear.

If someone has another solution, would be very helpful

Comment: are you having this issue while connecting via localhost to a site you are working on? or is this in someone else's app that is deployed in production?

Comment: the is my app, but it's not from localhost, it's from staging env, and same problem in production also

Comment: are you using the solana wallet adapter package? `window.phantom.solana` is not a common thing in the solana ecosystem

Comment: I suspect there is a state management issue within your app. likely because you are not attempting to connect to a solana wallet via the solana wallet adapter package. can you share come code snippets of how you are actually connecting to wallets?